# Arraylist of int[] array

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying a simple code and I can't figure out what is wrong. I am trying to add int[] array to an ArrayList. It gets added correctly. But once I have more than 1 element in the ArrayList, each of the element in the list is replaced by the latest value. I tried looking for possible errors, but I couldn't find any. I am giving my code and output here so that I can get help in figuring out the error in the code.

**Code:**

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<int[]> outer = new ArrayList<int[]>(); 
        int[] list = new int[7];
        int total = 2;
        int l = 3;
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            if((i+1) % l == 0)
            {
                list = new int[7];
                outer = new ArrayList<int[]>();
            }
            else {
                for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                {
                    int num = rand.nextInt(100);
                    list[j] = num;
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
                outer.add(list);
                System.out.println(outer.size());
                System.out.println(i);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outer.get(i)));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outer.get(0)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outer.get(1)));
    }

}
```

The output I get is:

**Output:**

```
[13, 50, 3, 47, 53, 57, 61]
1
0
[13, 50, 3, 47, 53, 57, 61]
[66, 96, 45, 2, 95, 1, 69]
2
1
[66, 96, 45, 2, 95, 1, 69]
[66, 96, 45, 2, 95, 1, 69]
[66, 96, 45, 2, 95, 1, 69]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the same `int[]` instance to the list repeatedly.

> ```
> else {
>     for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
>     {
>         int num = rand.nextInt(100);
>         list[j] = num;
>     }
>     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
>     outer.add(list);
>     System.out.println(outer.size());
>     System.out.println(i);
>     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outer.get(i)));
> }
> ```

Nothing in this list ever calls `list = new int[7]`. That means that each time through, you overwrite the contents of `list` with new random numbers, then add the same list to the `ArrayList` again.

`ArrayList` will happily let you add the same object over and over. It's just important to understand that putting an object into the `ArrayList` doesn't somehow copy it or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you add a new int[] to the ArrayList, you need to make a new array every time. Just move `int[] list = new int[7];` to inside the for loop so that it'll make a new int[] every time.

Answer (score 0):

You changed the values of the same `int[]` instance, whatever `i` is, and you put the same references of `int[]` to `outer`, so `outer.get(0)` and `outer.get(0)` will always be the same.